# How to absolutely position svgs to top and bottom of parent within an inline block in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an inline block so that elements sizes are dynamically width-matched constrained on the height of the elements.

How can I make the bottom element positioned at the bottom and the top element still be dynamically sized and positioned from the top?

Ideally I want to just say `position: absolute; bottom: 0` on the bottom element, and make the container have `height: 100%`, but doing so makes it so that the top element has size 0 (since having position absolute doesn't count for the container size when calculating from the bottom element?).

Links to relevant content on how to better understand positioning and dynamic sizing of elements would be greatly appreciated, because I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background: pink;
}

.top {
  max-height: 50vh;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.bottom {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 50vh;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="top" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <polygon points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
  </svg>
  <svg class="bottom" viewBox="0 0 100 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <polygon points="0,0 100,0 100,200 0,200" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `position: relative;` on your inlined element, i.e.

```
.container {
   display: inline-block;
   background: pink;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   position: relative;
 }

 .top {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   max-height: 50vh;
   min-width: 100%;
 }

 .bottom {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   height: 100%;
   max-height: 50vh;
   min-width: 100%;
 }
```

> A page element with relative positioning gives you the control to
>   absolutely position children elements inside of it.
>   s. https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: It looks like if I do that then the container can't get it's width and height defined via it's children. Is there a way around this so that the dynamic width matching still works?

Comment: Sry, small correction: in the example above you have to replace `50vh` by `50%`. Otherwise, you cannot make the width/height of this relative container dependent on absolute positioned elements because absolute positioned elements are not a "part" of the layout, they are positioned "above" the layout. So you have to put fixed height on container. But you could rewrite it with JS. Best!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally figure this out using an `display: inline-flex;` box as the container. It doesn't allow me to specify an absolute positioning for the children, but it does force the top element and bottom element to be spaced out.
Then the offset from the bottom and top can be specified with `padding-bottom: 10;` on the bottom element.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .container {
       display: inline-flex;
       flex-direction: column;
       justify-content: space-between;

       background: pink;
       height: 100%;
     }
     .top {
       min-width: 100%;
     }

     .bottom {
       height: 100%;

       max-height: 50vh;
       min-width: 100%;
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <svg class="top" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <polygon points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
  </svg>
  <svg class="bottom" viewBox="0 0 100 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <polygon points="0,0 100,0 100,200 0,200" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
  </svg>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```